# NameError: name 'View' is not defined in views.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to define a class in views.py which is inheriting generic view. The code is as follows. On running server I get the error that 
 class UserFormView(View):
NameError: name 'View' is not defined

although I have imported generic. Please let me know the reason.

```
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,render_to_response,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from .forms import UserForm

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'fosssite/home.html')
def login(request):
    c={}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('fosssite/login.html',c)

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class=UserForm
    template_name='fosssite/signup.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})


        #validate by forms of django
    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # not saving to database only creating object
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            #normalized data
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            #not as plain data
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save() #saved to database


def auth_view(request):
    username=request.POST.get('username', '')
    password=request.POST.get('password', '')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')#url in brackets
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid')

def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('fosssite/loggedin.html',{'fullname':request.user.username})

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render_to_response('fosssite/logout.html')

def invalid_login(request):
    return render_to_response('fosssite/invalid_login.html')
`
```

Comment: DId you copied this from somewhere ? Why the author doesn't have imported `View` ?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

Comment: That's because there is no View, Import it `from django.views.generic import View`

Comment: I am following tutorial of thenewboston on youtube

Comment: If you have the answer you wanted, please upvote the answers and accept one, in order to remove the question from the 'unanswered' queue

Comment: I have upvoted it, as I dont have enough badges yet so it might be visible later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either import `View` explicitly:

```
from django.views.generic import View
```

or refer to it as `generic.View`:

```
class UserFormView(generic.View):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 6):

The `View` name needs to be *imported*. Add the following import statement:

```
from django.views.generic import View
```

Or use the already imported `generic` module in

```
class UserFormView(generic.View)
#                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

in urls.py

```
 from my_app import views
```

eg code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from pro1 import views


urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    template="home.html"
    context={}
    return render(request,template,context)
```

guess it will solve the problem.